# Invalid constant value on Textformfield

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-design

I try to do show and hide password but it says  Invalid constant value on the _togglePasswordView, And _isHidden I wonder what I did wrong If someone know plz help

```
bool _isHidden = true;

 void _togglePasswordView() {
 setState(() {
  _isHidden = !_isHidden;
  });
}

TextFormField(
          obscureText: _isHidden,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Password',
            suffix: InkWell(
              onTap: _togglePasswordView,
              child: Icon(
                _isHidden ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

So lets make it clear about `const` keyword. When you use `const` keyword - you define a value constant from compile-time. It means - its value must be defined before the program even runs. So you may not but any run-time (created at some time when program is running) variables or conditions into constant constructors. Just remove the constant keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You're using something dynamic (here onTap function), inside a `const` constructor call

**JUST REMOVE `const` KEYWORD** and you'll be fine

Answer (score 0):

`const` Keyword means your variable will not change at application run-time.

what you're doing is saying to the complier that make `TextFormField` constant it will not change. while you changing the icon through run-time.

Just remove `const` and you well be fine